# How to an android room migrate for modifying the composite primary keys?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a statements entity in room db as follows

| date | amount | balance | tranParticular | tranAmt | tranId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday, 24 Jul 2023 | 1827 | XXX | xxxxxx | 1827 | xxxxxx |
| Monday, 24 Jul 2023 |  | XXX | xxxxxx | 1827 | xxxxxx |

Above entity has 3 composite primary keys ie tranParticular, amount, tranId .

I want to copy tranAmt to amount column. When  I will copy transAmt to amount  there will be conflict in the above example as a statement with the primary key already exist. In such cases I want to remove the transaction with blank amount key.

How can I perform such migration in android room?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe (assuming that you mean that you have a single composite primary key that consists of the 3 columns) the following could be used:-

```
@Query("UPDATE OR REPLACE tran SET amount = tranAmt")
```

Noting that this would be applied to ALL rows in the table (it would be easy to add a WHERE clause to restrict the rows to which the update is applied).

It is the `OR REPLACE` that is the important aspect, it is saying on a constraint conflict (the implied UNIQUE constraint of a primary key) instead of failing, replace the unchanged row with the new row.

Here's a demo of the above:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tran; /* just in case cleanup the demo environment */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tran (date TEXT, amount TEXT, balance TEXT, tranParticular TEXT, tranAmt TEXT, tranid TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(tranParticular, amount, tranId));
INSERT INTO tran VALUES
    ('Monday, 24 Jul 2023', 1827, 'XXX','xxxxxx',1827,'xxxxxx'),
    ('Monday, 24 Jul 2023', '', 'XXX','xxxxxx',1827,'xxxxxx'),
    ('Monday, 24 Jul 2023', 1827, 'YYY','yyyyyy',1827,'yyyyyy'),
    ('Monday, 24 Jul 2023', '', 'YYY','yyyyyy',1827,'yyyyyy'),
    ('Monday, 24 Jul 2023', 1827, 'ZZZ','zzzzzz',1827,'zzzzzz'),
    ('Monday, 24 Jul 2023', null, 'ZZZ','zzzzzz',1827,'zzzzzz')
;
SELECT * FROM tran; /* Before */
UPDATE OR REPLACE tran SET amount = tranAmt;
SELECT * FROM tran; /*After */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tran; /* cleanup demo environment */
```

- So the table is dropped (just for the demo)
- Then it is created and then populated with 3 sets of data each set consisting of a non-blank and a blank (the last is bull instead of blank, to show that it doesn't matter which)
- The data immediately after the load is output and is

  - [image]
- the suggested UPDATE is executed
- The data after the UPDATE is output and is :-

  - [image]

If the SELECTS are change from `SELECT * FROM tran` to `SELECT rowid,* FROM tran` then the **rowid** column, which is normally hidden is displayed. The **rowid** column exists for virtually all Room tables. Although if you have a single integer type column that is the primary key, then that column is an alias of the rowid column.

In short the rowid column uniquely identifies the row, is a number, and typically is 1, then 2 then 3 and so on.

Anyway the before the UPDATE then shows:-

- [image]
- the rowid being 1, 2, 3 ....

After the UPDATE it then shows:-

- [image]
- So as the attempt to update rowid 2 had a conflict with row 1, it has replaced row 1 (so row 1 is missing and so on).

  - as you have a composite primary key then it does not matter that rowid has been replaced, UNLESS that is, if other columns (balance and date) differ (it appears not from the data in your question).

Comment: Thanks! for my use case UPDATE OR IGNORE worked because the blank values were malformed.